# Angular routing in ASP.NET MVC application, How to use ngView in Asp.Net MVC _Layout.cshtml?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angular-routing, asp.net-mvc-layout

My Sample application has two MVC Controllers
 1.HomeController
 2.DetailsController

**HomeController.cs**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Home -> Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    Home - Index 
</div>
```

**DetailsController.cs**

```
public class DetailsController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**Details -> Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    Details - Index 
</div>
```

And in the _Layout.cshtml I have links to Home and Details.

**_ViewStart.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    <title>Angular Routing</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Layout</h1>
    <a href="/Home">Home</a>
    <a href="/Details">Details</a>
    <div ng-view>        
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the page loads, I get the content from _Layout.cshtml, but nothing gets loaded into the ngView container.

My guess, angular is trying to load the Home view as set in the route config for root route '/'. 
But its gets back the full view with _Layout.cshtml, which again tries to load the home page and this loop goes on indefinitely.

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);

    app.config(config)

    function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
                      .when('/', { 
                          templateUrl: "/Home",
                      })
                      .when('/Home', {
                          templateUrl: "/Home",
                      })
                      .when('/Details', {
                          template: "/Details",
                      });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }               
}());
```

I get this error in the Chrome console.

> *angular.js:13920 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*

So I tried to return Partial view from HomeController, which loaded the Home/Index view but the content in _Layout.cshtml did not load.

How to do angular routing in MVC application,is there a way to use the ngView in the _Layout.cshtml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you want to leverage Angular with ASP.Net MVC, you want to watch [AngularJS & ASP.NET MVC Playing nice Tutorial by Miguel Castro](https://vimeo.com/153759549).

You can view my sample project at [GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet).

The concept is to use MVC Route as main entry point for SPA, and then let Angular Route handle routing for individual pages. Main take away is MVC [RouteConfig.cs](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet/blob/master/src/Presentation/AngularAspNet.Web/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs) in which you want `users/{*catchall}`.

***FYI:*** in my sample project, I use MVC's **cshtml** as Angular View. You can ignore if you want to use regular html. In addition, I use Angular 1.5 Component so that I can convert to Angular 2 easily when it is available for production.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response..it really helped.